# Conflict of method call using Interface in Java

Tags: java, interface

Yesterday, I had an interview and I was given the following scenario:

There are 3 classes namely `Main.java, MobilePhone.java, DeskPhone.java` and one Interface `ITelephone.java`. `powerOn()` method is implemented in both classes `MobilePhone.java` and `DeskPhone.java`.

How can I call `powerOn()` method in `DeskPhone` class after creating an instance of `MobilePhone` class? In other word, how can I print "You are in DeskPhone class" and "You are in MobilePhone class" in last two calls in `Main` class?

Is there any another way to solve this problem without renaming `powerOn()` method in either of class?

Main.java

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ITelephone timsPhone;
    timsPhone = new DeskPhone(123456);
    timsPhone.powerOn();
    timsPhone = new MobilePhone(45678);
   //Question begins here 
    timsPhone.powerOn();
    timsPhone.powerOn();

    }
}
```

ITelephone.java

```
public interface ITelephone {
     void powerOn();
}
```

MobilePhone.java

```
public class MobilePhone implements ITelephone{

    private int myNumber;

    public MobilePhone(int myNumber) {
        this.myNumber = myNumber;
    }
    @Override
    public void powerOn() {
        System.out.println("You are in MobilePhone class");
    }
}
```

DeskPhone.java

```
public class DeskPhone implements ITelephone {

        private int myNumber;

        public DeskPhone(int myNumber) {
            this.myNumber = myNumber;
        }

        @Override
        public void powerOn() {
            System.out.println("You are in DeskPhone class");
        }
}
```

Comment: Use explicit casting `((DeskPhone) timsPhone).powerOn();`

Comment: @IvanPronin That just gives you a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: timsPhone loses reference to DeskPhone object when you assign MobilePhone to it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign the `MobilePhone` object to a different local variable.

In the current code, once the value of the `timsPhone` variable is replaced by the `MobilePhone` object, the `DeskPhone` object is unreachable and you cannot call its `powerOn()` method.

Suggested code:

```
ITelephone timsDeskPhone = new DeskPhone(123456);
timsDeskPhone.powerOn();
ITelephone timsMobilePhone = new MobilePhone(45678);
timsMobilePhone.powerOn();
timsDeskPhone.powerOn();
```

*Output*

```
You are in DeskPhone class
You are in MobilePhone class
You are in DeskPhone class
```

Comment: So, which one is prefrerable: to cast classes like ((DeskPhone) timsPhone).powerOn(); or to create seperate variable for each of the class?

Comment: @JayveerParmar Casting will cause `ClassCastException: MobilePhone cannot be cast to DeskPhone`, so that's not even an option. That is the **trap of the interview question**, to weed out prospect employees who don't know that.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to isolate in a static method the calling to your interface method..

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

          phonePowerOn(new DeskPhone(123456));

          phonePowerOn(new MobilePhone(45678));

    }


    static void phonePowerOn(ITelephone timsPhone){

        if (timsPhone != null){    
           timsPhone.powerOn();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you misunderstood the question, it was a trick, or possibly a little of both. Were those first four lines of `main` given to you like that? Did they tell you that you can't change them? Then the tactful response might be adding a few lines strategically like this:

```
static void main(String[] args){
  ITelephone timsPhone;
  timsPhone = new DeskPhone(123456);
  timsPhone.powerOn();
  ITelephone timsDeskPhone = timsPhone;
  timsPhone = new MobilePhone(45678);
  ITelephone timsMobilePhone = timsPhone;
  timsPhone = timsDeskPhone;
  timsPhone.powerOn();
  timsPhone = timsMobilePhone;
  timsPhone.powerOn();
}
```

This meets their specifications and shows an understanding of interfaces and references. With a question like this, the code is only of secondary importance. I would think they're really trying to assess communication, response to stress, and maybe even creativity. So just immediately saying, "You can't do that" really isn't much better than one that throws a `ClassCastException`.

The fun way is to fight fire with fire:

```
public class MobilePhone implements ITelephone{

  private int myNumber;

  public MobilePhone(int myNumber) {
      this.myNumber = myNumber;
  }

  private int powerOnCallCount = 0;

  @Override
  public void powerOn() {
    if (powerOnCallCount == 0){
      System.out.println("You are in DeskPhone class")
    } else {
      System.out.println("You are in MobilePhone class");
    }
    powerOnCallCount++;
  }
}
```

Again, we've only added code, it meets their specifications, and shows the same understanding of interfaces and references.

Or course, a sarcastic answer like this usually won't win points with the interview panel, but has use in the right situation. Remember, they're on trial, too. If I've already tried to gently steer towards a solution like the first and they don't back down, now I'm getting suspicious of their technical knowledge and company culture. If I've noticed a few other yellow flags, then I'd consider something like this to turn the tables. The kind of company I'd want to work for would appreciate that I already tried the tactful approach, met their specifications without compromising technical knowledge, and had enough spine to try my own test on them. I'd probably only resort to it if I was already convinced I didn't want the job, but wanted to give them one last chance to win me over.

Plus, if they practice test driven design, they'd pretty much have to offer me the job right on the spot.

Comment: They told me that how can you modify this program with only a few changes and print output as expected? As you mentioned in the program, it also works but I had to present code with optimization. So, if I create `timsMobilePhone.powerOn();
timsDeskPhone.powerOn();`, we get output as we want.